# Do Hazelcast EntryProcessors support "paging"?

Tags: paging, hazelcast

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
IMap map = hazelcastInstance.getMap(...);
EntryProcessor myEntryProcessor = ...
Predicate myPredicate = ...
PagingPredicate pagingPredicate = new PagingPredicate(myPredicate, 2);
map.executeOnEntries(myEntryProcessor, pagingPredicate);
```

So that the EntryProcessor would only be applied to the first two entries which satisfy myPredicate.  This doesn't seem to work.  Is this functionality not supported?